# How to attach a special class for ipad only - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the website desktop version looks fine and style are perfect. But when I view the website in the iPad certain area needs more styling(more padding and margins).

What I want to do is add a special class to the div, so that it only applies when I view it on the iPad. Then the particular class can handle all the extra stylings.

Is there a away track whether user is viewing through an iPad ? How can I do it? What could be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser/device detection is notoriously difficult to get right - partly for historical reasons (competing rendering engines, user-agent spoofing) and partly due to the plethora of user agents published by devices (see [here](http://www.user-agents.org/) for a non-complete list of agents/devices).

It is possible (simplistically) using the method in answers here, or perhaps using something like [UA-Parser-js](http://faisalman.github.com/ua-parser-js/) - a JavaScript-based User-Agent String Parser, which attempts to provide:

- Browser
- Engine
- OS
- Device

(It works, but with flaws).

Unless you're designing a web-based app **specifically for use on the iPad**, you should utilise a number of CSS media queries that reflow content based upon the width of the browser/viewport - an example of which for mobile devices might be:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div#wrapper {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Twitter bootstrap also comes with [responsive layouts](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)... In either case, you'll have to cater for both portrait and landscape modes and the fact that the different versions and resolutions of the iPad, which will affect quality, especially for images given the Retina displays of latter models:

**1st & 2nd generation:** 1024 × 768 px (132 PPI 4:3 aspect ratio)

**3rd & 4th generation:** 2048×1536 px (264 PPI)

**Mini:** 1,024x768 px (163 PPI)

Answer (score 3):

[HOW to detect Mobile devise using Jquery](http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/)

```
var isiPad = /ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

if (isiPad)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

> var ipad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
>
> if (ipad) $("#div").addClass('ipadClass');